# Testing/Mocking Workers in Controller Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a worker that is created inside of a controller action. The worker instantiates another service object. I've tested the worker and service object but I would like to test that the controller action initializes the worker correctly. I'm having troubles conceptually understanding what I should be mocking and the syntax for doing so.

My worker looks like this:

```
class RepoWorker 
  def perform(user)
    # business logic
    RepositorySyncer.new(user)
  end
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # business logic
    RepoWorker.new.async.perform(user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I think my test should look something like this but I can't quite get it to work.

```
it 'create a job to sync repos with github' do
  expect(RepoWorker).to receive(:perform)
  post :create, provider: :github
end
```

I'm using rspec-mocks 2.14.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you write

```
expect(RepoWorker).to receive(:perform)
```

you actually expect this to happen:

```
RepoWorker.perform
```

There are two ways you can achieve what you want. Using stub chains (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/message-chains-in-the-expect-syntax):

```
expect(RepoWorker).to receive_message_chain(:new, :async, :perform)
```

Or using any_instance (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class):

```
expect_any_instance_of(RepoWorker).to receive(:perform)
```

Edit:
For rspec 2.x the two methods are those:

```
worker = double
RepoWorker.stub_chain(:new, :async).and_return(worker)
expect(worker).to receive(:perform)

RepoWorker.any_instance.should_receive(:perform)
```

Comment: Hey Benzimmer, this was very helpful but I got this:
`undefined method 'receive_message_chain' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x0000010279bd20>`.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja Yes, sorry, that's already for rspec Version 3. For 2 you need to use stub_chain. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `RepoWorker` and make sure that a certain method is called. This way you ensure that nobody removes the `perform` call without causing any errors - at least you have a spec telling him that this was not a smart move.

So you could do something like this: (not tested, just by a quick search, syntax depends on exact mocking lib you use)

```
it 'create a job to sync repos with github' do
  RepoWorker.should_receive(:perform).at_least_once
  post :create, provider: :github
end
```

Comment: I'm using rspec-mocks 2.14.1. I'm using the expect syntax so I rewrote it as `expect(RepoWorker).to receive(:perform).at_least_once` but it said `undefined method` for `at_least_once` and when I left it out, `expected: 1 time with any arguments, received: 0 times with any arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving my problem.

```
it 'create a job to sync repos with github' do
  job = double('job')
  RepoWorker.stub_chain(:new, :async).and_return(job)
  expect(job).to receive(:perform)
  post :create, provider: :github
end
```